# Revit 2018.3 Build customized button

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I am trying to build a customized button on Revit 2018.3 which does the following:

On Revit's task bar under `collaborate` => `synchronize` => `Manage Connection to a Revit Server Accelerator`, I can `connect to different Revit Server Accelerators` by typing its name or IP address manually and hit connect.

Could I build all the actions above into one button? In another word, if the user clicks on the button, it will display the lists of accelerators and one can choose which one to connect to.

I have never programmed with Revit Macro nor Revit's code before, if you could provide some specific answers, it will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if `Manage Connection to a Revit Server Accelerator` is a built-in Revit command. [Built-in commands can be launched using `PostCommand`](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.3). Read those discussions to see whether that suits your use case.